# Как Отслеживать запросы ReacJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Прошу помощи найти инструмент для лова запросов ReacJS
Уже замучился весь инет обрыскал не нашел ответа, как отследить запросы ReactJS.

Наверно начну с самого начала, есть сайт где ставятся лайки так вот, через снифер пробую отловить запросы но вот чудо ничего не попадает при нажатие на лайк.

И да лайки когда ставишь нету привязки к соц.сети, вот часть html кода

```
<div class="img" data-reactid=".2.4.0:$137439720768.0.0"><img alt="Анжелика Фото:" src="//wx300.jpg" class="image" data-reactid=".2.4.0:$137439720768.0.0.0"><span class="popapActivate" data-reactid=".2.4.0:$137439720768.0.0.1"></span><span class="count" data-reactid=".2.4.0:$137439720768.0.0.2">55</span><button class="btnLike" style="cursor:pointer;" data-reactid=".2.4.0:$137439720768.0.0.3">Голосовать</button></div>
```

пробовал через фидлер использовать какой-то скрипт но что-то там не понял
как им пользоваться вот он.

вот сам скрипт для фидлера 
https://pastebin.com/sJ0umfNi

Может быть подойдет или есть другое решение, эффективнее ?

Comment: реакт никаким образом не связан с запросами. Скорее всего, где-то выше по дереву, висит обработчик, который на фазе перехвата ловит click и если это кнопка с нужными атрибутами,  то их и используют для отправки в качестве id. самое простое тоже документ или элемент подписать на события и что их не остановят.

Comment: Так а в чем особенность запросов в ReactJS? Отслеживайте запросы через DevTools.

Comment: @MaximZasorin в DevTools. не видно даже не видно в фидлере

Comment: @OlmerDale так как это сделать? Хотя бы кусок html примера.

Comment: Раз не видно в `DevTools`, то вомзожно вы смотрите `AJAX` запросы. Возможно, там взаимодействие реализовано через `Web Socket`. Попробуйте в  `DevTools` в `Network` перейти во вкладку `WS`. Там будут отображаться активные подключения.